# Clone Full Sandbox to Developer Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-clone

Is it possible to clone a Full Sandbox into a Dev Sandbox? I tried using clone but it wouldnt allow me as SF tried to do a like for like clone (full sandbox to full sandbox)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, no. From the documentation:

> When you clone a sandbox, all its data and metadata
>   are copied to the new sandbox. A cloned sandbox uses the same license
>   type as its source org. For example, to clone a Full sandbox you must
>   have a Full sandbox license available.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_clone.htm&type=5

Comment: Note also that a dev sandbox has a data limit of 200MB, where a full sandbox has the same limits as your production org. Even moving data via program or export/import, you quickly find yourself running out of room on a dev sandbox.

Comment: If you need this ability as much as I do, vote this idea up! https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXgDUAV

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a Sandbox requires same kind of sandbox type means
Full sandbox can be cloned from only full sandbox.
Same as partial copy sandbox can be cloned from partial copy sandbox.

Comment: How is this any different than the existing, accepted answer?